# Adding some space between TableRows in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm creating a table in Flutter which contains some TableRows, i just want to add some space between these rows.

```dart
Table(
    columnWidths: {0: FractionColumnWidth(.4)},
    children:[
        TableRow(children: [
        Text(
          'Original Title',
        ),
        Text(
          original_title,
        ),
      ]),
      TableRow(children: [
        Text(
          'Original Language',
        ),
        Text(
          original_language,
        ),
      ])
    ],
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient way but you can wrap the TableRow in a Padding Class

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: const Card(child: Text('Hello World!')),
)
```

Something along the lines of:

```
Table(
  columnWidths: {0: FractionColumnWidth(.4)},
  children:[
    TableRow(children: [
      Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0)
      child: Text(
        'Original Title',
      )),
      Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0)
      child: Text(
        original_title,
      )),
    ]),
    TableRow(children: [
      Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0)
      child: Text(
        'Original Language',
      )),
      Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0)
      child: Text(
        original_language,
      )),
    ]),
  ],
);
```

**Padding Class:**

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html

**EdgeInsets Class:**

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets-class.html

Comment: sorry not working it gives this "The element type 'Padding' can't be assigned to the list type 'TableRow'."

Comment: @YoussefHad could you try to add the padding around the text, see my edit. I'm not at my home computer so cannot check if it work.

Comment: This adds padding around the content IN a row, and not space BETWEEN rows. Thus if your cell has a background colour, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how i did it.

Create a constant, lets say `rowSpacer` as

```
const rowSpacer=TableRow(
                  children: [
                      SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                      )
                ]);
```

***Remember the number of SizedBox widgets to add above should be same as the number of colums in your table. For this case I have 2 colums, hence 2 SizedBoxes.***

Now use this constant to give spacing between rows.

```
              Table(
                  children: [
                       TableRow(
                          children: [
                            Text('Name:'),
                            Text('Aman kumar')
                            ]),
                       rowSpacer,                        //Using the Constant
                       TableRow(
                           children: [
                             Text('Date of Birth:'),
                             Text('September 27, 1998')
                            ]),
                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is to wrap the content of each table cell with a Padding like so:

```
    TableRow   (children: [
              TableCell(
                child:Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(EMAIL,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,


                  ),),
                ),
              ),
              TableCell(
                  child:Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(authUser.email),
                  )
              ),
            ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
TableRow(children: [
  TableCellPadded(child: const Text('Bla'))
])
```

```dart
class TableCellPadded extends StatelessWidget {
  final EdgeInsets? padding;
  final Widget child;
  final TableCellVerticalAlignment? verticalAlignment;

  const TableCellPadded(
      {Key? key, required this.child, this.padding,  this.verticalAlignment})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  TableCell build(BuildContext context) => TableCell(
      verticalAlignment: verticalAlignment ?? TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
      child: Padding(padding: padding ?? const EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child: child));
}
```

Found it here and adjusted it:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36816

Answer (score 0):

I just wrapped one of the elements with a `SizedBox` and set the `defaultVerticalAlignment` of the Table to middle:

```
Table(
  defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
  TableRow(
    children: [
      TableCell(
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
          child: Text('Hello world'),
         ),
       ),
    ]   
  )
)
```