# How can I space dataTable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, datatables

How can I space this way between rows

[see image of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5peU.png)

This is what I have a customDataTable

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SingleChildScrollView(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
child: DataTable(
dataRowHeight: 35,
headingRowHeight: 35,
headingRowColor:
MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => tableGrey),
dataRowColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => dataGrey),
columns: [
...headers.map((header) => DataColumn(label:
CustomText(
text: header,
size: 11,
color: Colors.white,
wordspacing: 1,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
),
)),
DataColumn(label:
CustomText(
text: "ACTION",
size: 11,
color: Colors.white,
wordspacing: 1,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
),
),
],
rows: List.generate(
tableData.length,
(index) => DataRow(
cells: [
...List.generate(
tableData[index].length,
(cellIndex) => DataCell(Text(tableData[index][cellIndex])),
),
DataCell(
IconButton(
icon: SvgPicture.asset('Assets/images/edit.svg'),
onPressed: () {
editActionsindex; // Trigger edit action based on the row index
},
),
),
],
),
),
),
);
}
}[see image of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39W4g.png)

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57526597/adding-some-space-between-tablerows-in-flutter